# Problems Installing TideSDK Developer Mac and Linux

Tags: sdk, tidesdk

So, today I spent the day trying to install TideSDK and the Developer app.

After getting it to run on the mac, I find that it won't do anything: The new project and the import buttons didn't do anything.

After that, I tried installing it on my 'virtual machined' ubuntu. And now I can't install it at all. I keep getting the error (Raised by an exception in the line 139 on the env.py file from the sdk): Exception: Could not find SDK Version 1.3.1-Beta.

I copied the sdk to the home folder and the root on Ubuntu and I copied it to the user side library on the mac, neither worked.

Now I don't have more ideas and I really wanted to make this working. 
Any  ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are not unpacking the archive into the directory. Do this using unzip with the -d option:

```
unzip -d TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-osx-x86-64.zip ~/Library/Application Support/TideSDK
```

It should be as simple as that. You will have modules, runtime and sdk in this folder afterwards:

```
├── TideSDK
    ├── modules
    ├── runtime
    ├── sdk
```

Comment: Thanks @fairwinds. This command worked and it has done the unzip in the right folder. I did it on OSX, so the command should have the -d option after the .zip instead.
But my TideDeveloper App still doesn't work. It opens but when I try to import or create a project the app doesn't do nothing. 
Is this a common problem?

Comment: You will have to be specific about what OS you are on and what version of TideSDK-Developer you are attempting to use.

Comment: TideSdk 1.3.1 for MacOSX.
TideSdk 1.4.2 Developer also for MacOSX.
I'm running MacOSX Snow Leopard, V-10.6.8

Comment: Unfortunately TideSDK-1.3.1 supports development on OSX 10.7 Lion and OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion only at this time. TideSDK-1.3.2 will restore support for 10.6 Snow Leopard when it is released.

Comment: Ok, got it now. No problem, I'll just wait. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is comprehensive document related to how to install and get started with TideSDK. Can you please try to use the Getting Started docs and follow instructions given:

http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started

the developer app expects the files to be installed in particular directories. You need to extract the files in appropriate directories.

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Hi mital.   

I did used this documentation, that's why I said that I copied the sdk folder to the right place in both cases.   

Justo to be sure, from the documentation:  

For Mac OSX:  
  
~/Library/Application Support/TideSDK  
Heads up! This is the library folder inside your user folder, NOT the global library folder.  
  
On Linux:  
  
~/.tidesdk  
  
This means my library on the mac os and home/myusr on the linux, right?

Comment: but it didn't :/
thanks anyway :) Still leaving the question opened for future possible answers :P

Comment: you can come online on irc .. there would be people there to help you fixing your specific problems.

irc.freenode.net --> #tidesdk

Answer (score 0):

Found that SDK has the "C" Drive hard coded in for file locations--in a number of places.  Long story, but I don't have a C drive, windows is on my E drive.

I fixed this by opening sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\env.py in a text editor and changing lines 85 and 86

```
    elif (self.target_os == 'win32'):
        self.install_dirs = [
            p.join(os.environ['APPDATA'], 'TideSDK'),
            # TODO: Is there a better way to determine this directory?
            'E:\\ProgramData\\TideSDK',
            'E:\\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\TideSDK'
        ]
```

also in win32_app.py lines 193 and 195

```
def get_wix_bin_directory(self):
    path = p.join("E:\\", "Program Files", "Windows Installer XML v3", "bin")
    if not p.exists(path):
        path = p.join("E:\\", "Program Files (x86)", "Windows Installer XML v3", "bin")
    if not p.exists(path):
        raise Exception('Could not find WiX v3 bin directory')
    return path
```